# Comment referenced class throws ReferenceError at runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd, durandal

This builds with no errors at compile time,  but when I run it, I'm getting a ReferenceError when I try to use the net class. (net is not defined)

```
//chat.ts file
/// <reference path="../client/net.ts" />
class chat {
    constructor(public chatHub: any) {
       net.call(chatHub.server.getUsers());
    } 
}

//net.ts file
class net {
    public call(callback: () => any): any {
        //stuff here
        return callback();
    }
}
```

Things I tried:

- Turn net into a module and export the function. Won't work because doing an export triggers the AMD module transformation, which then requires Importing it in my chat class, which turns my chat class into an AMD module rendering it out of scope for all the classes that reference chat.ts.  Cascade of AMD doom.
- Tried all possible permutations of static, public, module, class and export.  No dice.

All I want to do is use the utility functions on my net class from my chat class.

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `net.call(chatHub.server.getUsers);` ?

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I hadn't run that code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remember to add the net.js file to the page (somewhere above the chat.js file)? Just referencing it in the TypeScript doesn't load it for you.

You either need to use the AMD module definition in conjunction with a loader like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/), or make sure all the .js files you need are added (either one at a time, or bundled) to your page. All the comment reference does is tell the compiler where to find the type information.

Comment: I'm using Durandal, which is set up to bundle everything in it's subfolder.  The problem is that it's not triggering something that tells it to bundle this file, and can't figure out why

Comment: That's a slightly different question than the one you posed. Working with Durandal, you're better IMO packaging your code as a module and loading it with require. I'll update.

Comment: My chat class for example, is used from my Lobby class,  and that works just fine, it's bundled and referenced correctly.

Comment: So your problem is nothing to do with TS, really - just an issue with Durandal bundling. I've never used that part of Durandal myself - I've always worked with AMD modules.

Comment: Sanity check: net.js is located somewhere under your Durandal App/ folder, right? http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Optimizing-On-Dot-Net/

Comment: Yes, it's under App/client/net.ts, I was assuming that everything inside App is bundled.

Comment: That's what the docs say. Are you sure it's compiling? Have you checked there's actually JS to bundle? Anyway - now we've triggered the discussion warning, so I'll leave you to it. Good luck.